# How to define an exception router in chain after aggregator

Tags: spring-integration

I using Spring integration to aggregate messages into one and then send by FTP out bound adapter, I want to move the aggregated messages in a specific folder when outbound FTP server is not available(org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException), other exceptions will log by console.

Here is my Configuration

```
<int:chain id="transformChain" input-channel="inboundChannel">
    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="file_name" expression="payload.name"/>
        <int:header name="correlationId" expression="${header.enricher.correlationId}"/>
        <int:header name="sum" expression="${header.enricher.sum}"/>
    </int:header-enricher>

    <int:transformer ref="fileNameToContentTransformer"/>

    <int:aggregator send-partial-result-on-expiry="true"
                    release-strategy-expression="#this.size() == new Integer([0].headers.sum)"
                    group-timeout="${aggregator.group-timeout}"
                    message-store="messageStore"
                    expire-groups-upon-completion="true"
                    correlation-strategy-expression="headers.correlationId"/>
    <int:transformer ref="xmlToJsonTransformer"/>
    <ftp:outbound-channel-adapter remote-directory="${ftp.out.remote.directory}"
                                  session-factory="ftpOutClientSessionFactory" auto-create-directory="true"
                                  remote-filename-generator="fileNameGenerator" charset="UTF-8"
                                  temporary-file-suffix=".writing">
    </ftp:outbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:exception-type-router >
        <int:mapping exception-type="org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException" channel="undeliveredChannel"/>
        <int:mapping exception-type="java.lang.Exception" channel="myErrorChannel"/>
    </int:exception-type-router>
</int:chain>
```

However I met such exception when try to start.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: All handlers except for the last one in the chain must implement the MessageProducer interface. Object of class [org.springframework.integration.ftp.outbound.FtpMessageHandler] must be an instance of interface org.springframework.integration.core.MessageProducer
at org.springframework.util.Assert.instanceCheckFailed(Assert.java:389)
at org.springframework.util.Assert.isInstanceOf(Assert.java:327)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.configureChain(MessageHandlerChain.java:119)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.onInit(MessageHandlerChain.java:99)
at org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.afterPropertiesSet(IntegrationObjectSupport.java:176)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
```

Anyone can tell me how to achieve this?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a component to the chain after the `ftp:outbound-channel-adapter` because it produces no result.

See the [retry-and-more sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/retry-and-more#expression-evaluating-advice-demo) for an example of how to handle exceptions by adding an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` to the outbound adapter.